# SVN ignoring a '.a' file

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, svn

I am trying to add a '.a' file in my XCode project but it is getting ignored by SVN and so I am not able to add it in the repository. Any clue what could be the reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah you will have to do it manually. Just navigate to it in a console and perform a svn add file_name.a and it should work.

Comment: No problem. SVN through Xcode isn't perfect so if you every have problems you should first try it through console to fix it.

Comment: This works but you have to do it separately for every file. Seva's answer solves the problem for good.

Answer (score 8):

SVN has a global ignore list. By default, it includes masks for most popular types of generated files. .a is one of those.

The ignore list is in the SVN config file, under miscellany/global-ignores. The config file is at ~/.subversion/config. It's not visible in Finder by default.

Comment: Under Mountian Lion, it appears that these lines are commented out in ~/.subversion/config and the .a files are still not even seen under the SVN client, Versions.